# Change colour of Glassfish 3.1 Community Edition Domain Application Server

Tags: glassfish, glassfish-3

How do you change the default colour scheme on a Glassfish 3.1 community edition? To distinguish between different environments.

Comment: Mostly stuff like backgrounds of screens. I want to be able to distinguish them easily in a visual way.

Comment: About what kind of screens are you talking?

Comment: The ones in the Domain Application Server, so stuff like the login screen, and all of the "server management" kind of screens. Where you deploy applications, add JDBC pools, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't find an example but it looks like it is possible to change the layout of Glassfishs Admin UI via a so called integration-point which looks similar to this:

```
    <integration-point 
            id="myOwnBrand" 
            type="org.glassfish.admingui:customtheme" 
            priority="2" 
            content="myOwnBrand.properties" 
    />
```

The Oracle docs for [Changing the Theme or Brand of the Administration Console](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1749/6nmnal4su/index.html#ghpls) contains some information about the different integration point, but there is example how the properties file should look like.

There is also a [Custom Theme Plugin for GlassFish V3 Admin Console](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.admingui/console-community-branding-plugin)  but I can't find any details about how to use that.

**See also:**

- [Glassfish Administration Console Architecture - Implementing a Console Provider](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19776-01/820-6583/ghmof/index.html)
- [org.glassfish.admingui:customtheme Integration Point](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18930_01/html/821-2415/ghpiz.html)
- [GlassFish Modularity System, How extend GlassFish CLI and Web Administration Console](https://weblogs.java.net/blog/kalali/archive/2010/03/29/glassfish-modularity-system-how-extend-glassfish-cli-and-web-administ)